# ElasticSearch Aggregation for Unique Field Value

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to gather statistics over a field names "CpuEff" for each unique field "DESIRED_CMS_Dataset". So I wrote this,

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/cms-2016-03-30/job/_search?pretty=true' -D'
{
        "aggregations" : {
                "data" : {
                  "terms": {
                        "field": "DESIRED_CMSDataset"
                        "order": {
                                "cnt" : "desc"
                        }
                   },
                   "aggregations" : {
                        "data_stats" : {
                                "extended_stats" : { "field" : "CpuEff" }
                        }
                   }
                 }
        }
}'
```

This gives an neither gives me the statistics nor gives me just the field DESIRED_CMSDataset. Instead I get a bunch of

```
{
      "_index" : "cms-2016-03-30",
      "_type" : "job",
      "_id" : "crab3-4@vocms066.cern.ch#6248657.0#1459314096",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "CoreHr" : 1.1066666666666667,
        "DataCollectionDate" : 1459318128,
        "JobStartDate" : 1459314144,
        "Requirements" : false,
...
```

So I would like to fix my query so that I only see  DESIRED_CMSDataset and the results that [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html) says I should get (ie avg, sum, ...) for each unique value of DESIRED_CMSDataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default elasticsearch returns 20 documents in search request you can add *"size" :0* to output only aggregations

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/cms-2016-03-30/job/_search?pretty=true' -D'
{
        "size": 0, 
        "aggs" : {
                "data" : {
                  "terms": {
                        "field": "DESIRED_CMSDataset"
                        "size": 0,
                        "order": {
                                "_count" : "desc"
                        }
                   },
                   "aggs" : {
                        "data_stats" : {
                                "extended_stats" : { "field" : "CpuEff" }
                        }
                   }
                 }
        }
}'
```

Comment: Perfect except I only get 10 aggregations back. I want all of them for every possible unique DESIRED_CMSDataset. Solving this will fully solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: you can use *size* field in *terms* aggregation. If set to 0, the size will be set to Integer.MAX_VALUE. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. You are the first person who has actually answered any of my ElasticSearch questions on StackOverflow. Most people just point me documentation that just confuses me more.